# Should I set up social authentication from the beginning?

Tags: django

I want to build a Django app that allows users to sign up using their Facebook account (but isn't necessary).  However, I don't feel like dealing with the social auth stuff from the get go because I'd rather focus on the meat of my app. So, can I make an app without social authentication and just "plug it in" at the end or is it something I should set up from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to plug it in later. However, one decision you must make at the start and stick to is the user model you're going to use.
Whether users register/login to your site with a social account or not, a local account will need to be created. Social accounts are linked to that local account.
If you are happy for the local account to use the default user model and have users log in to your site with a username and password, then go right ahead.

If you'd like the local account to use an email instead of a username then you've a bit of work to do.
The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) explain your options and provide a working example at the bottom .

Assuming you're going to use django-allauth, [this tutorial](http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/) will get you started and [this demo](https://github.com/aellerton/demo-allauth-bootstrap) will give you most of the templates you need.
The demo gives an example of customizing the user model to use email instead of a username but it is not quite complete.